# Can I store file contents to a variable in a shell script?

Tags: shell, solaris, sh

Say I have a file *file.txt* with data (say '100') in it. I want to read the contents of this file to a variable for future processing. I want this to work on both Linux and Solaris. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this line:

```
VAR=$(cat file.txt)
```

or

```
VAR=$(head -1 file.txt)
```

EDIT 1:

**Using output of Unix commands to set variables**

One of the best things about shell scripting is that it's very easy to use any Unix command to generate the output and use it to set the variable.

In this example, I'm running a date command and saving its output as values for my variables:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
STARTED=`date`
sleep 5
FINISHED=`date`
#
echo "Script start time: $STARTED"
echo "Script finish time: $FINISHED"
```

If I run this simple script, I see the following:

```
ubuntu$ /tmp/1.sh
Script start time: Wed May 7 04:56:51 CDT 2008
Script finish time: Wed May 7 04:56:56 CDT 2008
```

The same approach can be used for practically any scenario.

so the mvp's answer will works on any unix shell:

```
F=`cat file.txt`
```

Just try with backtick `` ` `` not `'` single qoute

Comment: i have tried the above 2 . It does not work on solaris. It gives syntax error

Comment: what is your shell interpreter: sh , bash, csh or ksh ?

Comment: Plain `sh` on Solaris is a fairly old shell; it doesn't support `$(...)` AFAICR, so you have to use ``var=`...` `` instead (noting that they are back-ticks).  In `bash`, you'd be able to use `var=$(<file.txt)` which doesn't actually launch a sub-shell.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
 VAR=`cat file.txt`
```

If you want to get only first line of file, use this:

```
 VAR=`head -1 file.txt`
```

Comment: VAR = 'cat file.txt
echo $var
above outputs cat file.txt

Comment: Make sure you use backtick, not `'`. If not sure, copy and paste it - it DOES work

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the following

```
VAR=$(<file)
```

It worked when I needed the second line in a two line file to store as a variable in bash.